# OneToMany from JPA/JDO to Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am moving from Datanucleus to Objectify. How do I rewrite the following `OneToMany` code for Objectify?

```
@Entity
public class Person{
  …
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Dog> dogs = new HashSet<Dog>();
  …
}
```

Right now to query Person and get all my dogs, I simply do

```
public Person findById(String uid) {
  EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
  try {
    String jpql = "SELECT a FROM Person a WHERE a.uid = :uid";
    TypedQuery<Person> q = mgr.createQuery(jpql, Person.class);
    q.setParameter("uid", uid);
    return q.getSingleResult();
  } catch (Exception e) {// entityNotFoundException or NoResultException
    return null;
  } finally {
    mgr.close();
  }
}
```

And I can iterate through dogs as

```
Person owner = personDao.findById(id.getUid());
for (Dog dog : owner.getDogs()) {
  //… do stuff
}
```

By the way, `uid` is not annotated as `@Id` so that it is not a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if you want an object A to "have many" object B's you have to make A have a field that holds a list of pointers (Keys) to the B-s. This is described on the oficial Objectify's documentation [1].

[1] https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#one-to-many-relationships

Comment: This would mean that I have to subsequently query for each element of B by key when I need it.

Comment: How about the `@Container` tag? There isn't much detail in the explanation. Would it serve my purpose?

Comment: For your first comment: yes you'll need to do it. Remember that Datastore is No Relational DB.
Second comment: I'd say no. The `@container` tag only makes sense if you are making use of [Embebbed Classes/Entities](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#embedded-classes). I don't see how this scheme will serve your purpose. Also, `@Container` fields are not persisted in the native datastore. They are populated only when the entity is loaded.